# How do I turn this svg path into a slice in a donut chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg

For starters, I used [this](https://hackernoon.com/a-simple-pie-chart-in-svg-dbdd653b6936) as a reference for to draw a pie chart, however I changed a few details. My goal is to turn this into a donut chart rather than a pie chart, and I like using the path element.

I start off with the svg element

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 2 2">

</svg>
```

And then loop through an array of data to draw each slice.

```
int count = 0;

double xCurr = 1;
double yCurr = 0;
double totalPercentage = 0;

string slices = "";

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    double percent = GetPercentage(array[i], GetTotal());
    totalPercentage += percent;
    int largeArcFlag = percent > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;

    slices += "<g><path fill='" + GetColor(i) + "' d='M" + (xCurr + 1) + "," + (yCurr + 1) + " A1,1,0," + largeArcFlag + ",1," + ((GetXYVals(totalPercentage))[0] + 1) + "," + ((GetXYVals(totalPercentage))[1] + 1) + " L1,1 A0.58,0.58,0," + LargeArcFlag + ",0," + ((GetXYVals(totalPercentage))[0] + 1) + "," + ((GetXYVals(totalPercentage))[1] + 1) + "'></path></g>";

    xCurr = (GetXYVals(totalPercentage))[0];
    yCurr = (GetXYVals(totalPercentage))[1];
}
```

The GetTotal(), GetXYVals() & GetPercentage() methods:

```
private double GetPercentage(int Value, int Total)
{
    return ((double)Value / Total);
}

private double[] GetXYVals(double percent)
{

    double x = Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * percent);
    double y = Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * percent);

    double[] set = { x, y };

    return set;
}

private int GetTotal()
{
    int Total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        Total += array[i];
    }

    return Total;
}
```

Using the dataset `45, 20, 2, 14, 24`

The svg ends up looking like

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 2 2">
    <g>
        <path fill="#1b998b" d="M2,1 A1,1,0,0,1,0.099031132097581,1.43388373911756 L1,1 A0.58,0.58,0,0,0,0.099031132097581,1.43388373911756"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#fffd82" d="M0.099031132097581,1.43388373911756 A1,1,0,0,1,0.266948128170174,0.319827262229081 L1,1 A0.58,0.58,0,0,0,0.266948128170174,0.319827262229081"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#ff9b71" d="M0.266948128170174,0.319827262229081 A1,1,0,0,1,0.353400398784201,0.237170428137733 L1,1 A0.58,0.58,0,0,0,0.353400398784201,0.237170428137733"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#e84855" d="M0.353400398784201,0.237170428137733 A1,1,0,0,1,1.13423326581766,0.00905023823206519 L1,1 A0.58,0.58,0,0,0,1.13423326581766,0.00905023823206519"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path fill="#6b2e98" d="M1.13423326581766,0.00905023823206519 A1,1,0,0,1,2,1 L1,1 A0.58,0.58,0,0,0,2,1"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[image: The svg]

My question is, how would you calculate the lineto x y values, since for a donut setting them to 1,1 isnt going to work, and how do you calculate the second arcto x y values? Will all of the other values I'm currently using work for a donut chart as well?

Answer (score -1):

One Witty (or Silly) way of making a Donut Chart from a Pie Chart is to Draw a Circle (of background color) with a smaller radius (Depending upon how thick your donut must be).

In the ugly Example below - After creating a Pie (Circular) chart - I added a White background circle over it. (off course this is MS-Paint -- you can do better with C#).

[image]